# "know you are not alone" Or "know that you are not alone"

Tags: conjunctions, relative-pronouns, ellipsis

> know you are not alone..."
>
> know **that** you are not alone..."

If I use the line in a poetic way, does the first sentence sounds non-grammatical without *that*?

Comment: Are these standalone phrases (a line of verse by itself)? If not, could you give whole phrase examples?

Answer (score 2):

In your example "that" is a conjunction introducing a subordinate clause used to report someone’s thoughts.

After *know* (and numerous other verbs used to report a statement or someone’s thoughts, such as *admit, agree, claim, see, say, ask, write, explain*, etc...)  we use a reported clause beginning with the conjunction "that". In informal speech and in writing, the conjunction "that" is often omitted.

> I know you are not alone.
>   I know that you are not alone.

> He said he was coming.
>   He said that he was coming.

> I forgot I had to pay that bill.
>   I forgot that I had to pay that bill.

All these sentences are correct.

This type of sentence is called a **that-clause**, even when *that* is omitted.

You can find more [here](http://www.englishpractice.com/grammar/clauses-3/) or [here](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/that-clauses).

Comment: Thanks for those examples and explaining it so well. It helps to understand, if "that" could be omitted in certain sentences.

Answer (score 1):

It's fine without the "that". "Know you are not alone" (in quotes) in google gets about 16,200,000 results.

Comment: Note that a google search, even with quotes, is [not](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/websearch/50nj7P22N68) [reliable](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/websearch/0P1wloPuvSE). I would suggest to use google's ngram viewer. See [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=know+you+are+not%2Cknow+that+you+are+not&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cknow%20you%20are%20not%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cknow%20that%20you%20are%20not%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the ngram viewer link... Nico.

Comment: Thanks Codeswitcher for confirming without "that" it's ok.